# python 3.7 sched running sleep to neg value

Tags: python, scheduler

**Revised question**

Is there a way by using treading and sched to create a for loop where you run a script exactly every second jumping between 3 treads constantly for as long as you need it Like

```
for thread01 in schead:
    run at 00:00:01.0000
    else(thread02):
        run at 00:00:02.0000
        else(thread03):
            run at 00:00:03.0000
```

and have it constantly loop does mitigating the drift and neg sleep value as each time the code runs on a tread it has 1000 milliseconds to execute before the next second

I have tested and the session_create runs between 480 and 530 milliseconds constantly to execute

**Old Question** old Code to help mitigate time drift

```
from main import session_create
import sched, datetime, threading

def timestamp():
    next_call = time.time()
    while True:
          session_create()
          print (datetime.datetime.now())
          nextcall = next_call+1;
          time.sleep(nextcall - time.time())
timerThread = threading.Thread(target=timestamp)
timerThread.daemon = True
timerThread.start()
```

Comment: Do you not get errors with this line `file.close()`? Because the `with` structure takes care of closing it already.

Comment: No none. But thank you for making me aware of this. I am taking out unnecessary bits as i learn of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the closest I could get to what i wanted as I knew that the code that needed tobe called and run every second, and I knew it takes between 500 to 600 milliseconds to run.

I used threading.Timer to run the code every 900 milliseconds and this causes the code to run at least once every second and bypassing the time drift i was experiencing.

```
from Sessions import session
import sched, time, threading

Event_scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

##
start_time = time.time()

def run():
    threading.Timer(0.9, run).start()
    session()
run()
```

The down side of this is simple math every Nth second ill have a point where the code ran twice (example 23:59:01:0050 and again at 23:59:01:0950). But the extra data is easily removed by finding the duplicates 23:59:01 == 23:59:01 and removing one of the two